# ASP.NET MVC Architecture - Generic repository pattern

Tags: architecture, asp.net-mvc-3, separation-of-concerns, neural-network

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and I'm trying to figure out the *right* way of coding in it.
I'm trying to implement a multi-layer architecture with a generic repository for data access.

Here's what I was used to do in Webforms solutions (each item is a separate project):

- MyProject.Data (Entity Framework .Edmx + Generic Repository)
- MyProject.Business.Services (Calls repository, applies business rules, etc)
- MyProject.Business.DomainModel (Entities)
- MyProject.UI (ASP.NET Webforms app)

Now in an MVC pattern:
I think I should define my ViewModels in *MyProject.Business.DomainModel* and my Models in *MyProject.Business.Services*. And Data layer remains unchanged. In summary:

- MyProject.Data (Entity Framework .Edmx + Generic Repository)
- MyProject.Business.Services (Models implementation)
- MyProject.Business.DomainModel (POCO Entities + ViewModels)
- MyProject.UI (ASP.NET MVC app)

I'll appreciate your comments about this approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the onion architecture. http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/

Codecampserver is an implementation example. http://codecampserver.codeplex.com/

SharpArchitecture is another example to look at. http://code.google.com/p/sharp-architecture/

They dont do things exactly the same but they do separate concerns.

Comment: Thanks Derek. Very informative stuff. Do you have any idea about my design architecture as well?

Comment: I think UI and services are probably ok.  I'd put ViewModels in the UI project as they're models of screens/views and are concerned with the UI.  I would put poco's and the repository interfaces in DomainModel and the edmx and the implementation of the repositories in Data.

Comment: If I add ViewModel in UI, I will not have access to them from Services. I guess I'll need them to do some business logic. Also what's the point of putting repository interface in Domain model? I think I won't need it in anywhere but DAL.

Comment: I don't think your model implementation belongs to the Services layer, I'd put them in the DomainModel layer and leave the Services layer for er... well.. services :)

Comment: With the onion arch. all of the interfaces and domain model go in the core.  So any service and repository interfaces go in core.  The domain model is in core.  Then the implementations go in other assemblies.  Then, UI only references core and not the implementations.